# Overriding "+=" in Python? (__iadd__() method)

Tags: python, operators, overriding

Is it possible to override += in Python?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes, override the [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__) method. Example:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.number += other.number
    return self
```

Comment: You shouldn't implement `__iadd__` if your class represents immutable objects. In that case just implement `__add__` which will be used to override `+=` instead. For example you can use `+=` on immutable types such as strings and integers, which couldn't be done using `__iadd__`.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths, so are you saying that if you've implemented `__add__` you don't necessarily have to implement `__iadd__`? I read the duplicate question you linked but I just got confused because I don't understand why you would implement `__add__` so that it mutates the object

Comment: @ScottGriffiths meant ask "you don't necessarily have to implement `__iadd__` __to use +=__?"

Comment: @JosieThompson: If you don't implement `__iadd__` then it will use `__add__` if available, which is usually just fine. So in that case `a += b` would be equivalent to `a = a + b`, which assigns a new value to `a` instead of changing `a` itself. Having a separate `__iadd__` is typically a nice optimisation rather than something you need to use the `+=` operator.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths Is the same true for `__imul__`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Yes the same goes for `__imul__` and other in-place operators (`__isub__`, `__idiv__` etc.) They should only be defined for mutable objects, and if not defined all will fall back to the standard operators in the same way. So `a *= 2` is equivalent to `a = a * 2` if `__imul__` is not defined for the type of `a`.

Answer (score 47):

In addition to what's correctly given in answers above, it is worth explicitly clarifying that when `__iadd__` is overriden, the `x += y` operation does NOT end with the end of `__iadd__` method.

Instead, it ends with `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. In other words, Python assigns the return value of your `__iadd__` implementation to the object you're "adding to", AFTER the implementation completes.

This means it is possible to mutate the left side of the `x += y` operation so that the final implicit step fails. Consider what can happen when you are adding to something that's within a list:

`>>> x[1] += y # x has two items`

Now, if your `__iadd__` implementation (a method of an object at `x[1]`) erroneously or on purpose removes the first item (`x[0]`) from the beginning of the list, Python will then run your `__iadd__` method) & try to assign its return value to `x[1]`. Which will no longer exist (it will be at `x[0]`), resulting in an `ÌndexError`.

Or, if your `__iadd__` inserts something to beginning of `x` of the above example, your object will be at `x[2]`, not `x[1]`, and whatever was earlier at `x[0]` will now be at `x[1]`and be assigned the return value of the `__iadd__` invocation.

Unless one understands what's happening, resulting bugs can be a nightmare to fix.

Comment: do you happen to know why `__iadd__` is designed like that? i.e. why it assigns the return value rather than just settling with in-place mutation?

Comment: @joel Because that's how it must work with immutable types such as `str` and `int`, and, more importantly, `tuple` and `namedtuple`.

Comment: if your iadd method changes ("mutates") the object itself, i.e. self, it should "return self" at the end, or else, although the object will be modified, the variable that was holding on to it will be set to None, and if that was the only thing holding on to the object, the object gets garbage collected.

Comment: An easy-to-forget-or-overlook thing is that a variable is just a holder for something, it's not the thing itself.  So if I say x = FooObject, x is a variable that is *holding a pointer* to a FooObject, but I could say y = x and both y and x would refer to the same object.  In that situation, x += "more stuff" could change the object, return None, x would hold None and y would hold the original object, but object has been changed internally.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to overloading `__iadd__` (remember to return self!), you can also fallback on `__add__`, as x += y will work like x = x + y. (This is one of the pitfalls of the += operator.)

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...   def __add__(self, other):
...     return A(self.x + other.x)
>>> a = A(42)
>>> b = A(3)
>>> print a.x, b.x
42 3
>>> old_id = id(a)
>>> a += b
>>> print a.x
45
>>> print old_id == id(a)
False
```

It even [trips up experts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045344/how-do-you-create-an-incremental-id-in-a-python-class/1045368#1045368):

```
class Resource(object):
  class_counter = 0
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = self.class_counter
    self.class_counter += 1

x = Resource()
y = Resource()
```

What values do you expect `x.id`, `y.id`, and `Resource.class_counter` to have?

Comment: Your second example has nothing to do with iadd or +=.  The same result occurs if you use self.class_counter = self.class_counter + 1

It's just a scoping issue, using self when Resource should be used.

Comment: It's an example of how using += can lead to problems. If you're overloading __iadd__, then you're opening users of your class (including yourself) to this, and, at the very least, you should know the issue exists beforehand.

Comment: @FogleBird: It is a gotcha because `foo += bar` can either mean "mutate the existing object that `foo` refers to" or "assign `foo` to the object resulting from the expression `foo + bar`". And which happens depends on whether `foo` has an `__iadd__` method.

Comment: In your example, `foo` is just a number.  It's not an instance of the class you're defining.  You never call either `+` or `+=` with the `Resource` class.  It's a gotcha, but it's not related to having or not having a `__iadd__` method defined or not defined for `Resource`.

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

> For instance, to execute the statement
>   x += y, where x is an instance of a
>   class that has an __iadd__() method,
>   x.__iadd__(y) is called.