# Why don't I see pipe operators in most high-level languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, concurrency, shell, pipe

In Unix shell programming the [pipe operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(computing)) is an extremely powerful tool. With a small set of core utilities, a systems language (like C) and a scripting language (like Python) you can construct extremely compact and powerful shell scripts, that are automatically parallelized by the operating system.

Obviously this is a very powerful programming paradigm, but I haven't seen pipes as first class abstractions in any language other than a shell script. The code needed to replicate the functionality of scripts using pipes seems to always be quite complex.

So my question is why don't I see something similar to Unix pipes in modern high-level languages like C#, Java, etc.? Are there languages (other than shell scripts) which do support first class pipes? Isn't it a convenient and safe way to express concurrent algorithms?

Just in case someone brings it up, I looked at the F# pipe-forward operator (forward pipe operator), and it looks more like a function application operator. It applies a function to data, rather than connecting two streams together, as far as I can tell, but I am open to corrections.

**Postscript**: While doing some research on implementing coroutines, I realize that there are certain parallels. In a [blog post](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/martinw/archive/2006/04/19/5345.aspx) Martin Wolf describes a similar problem to mine but in terms of coroutines instead of pipes.

Comment: I've really wondered the same thing, but never thought to actually ask.

Comment: FWIW you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartmann_pipeline

Comment: Keep in mind that the "data" that the F# forward pipe operator applies the function to can itself be a function, or a sequence of functions.

Comment: @Mark, the Harmann pipeline was very much related to what I wanted. 

@Brinary: I don't know how to apply data to a sequence of functions, are they composed together? I'm assuming the data isn't applied to them all concurrently.

Comment: It also blows my mind that so few languages do this well. Chaining iterators in java is a PITA.

Comment: I don't know what kind of an answer you're expecting to this question, other than 'because they didn't put it in' or 'because they didn't think of it' or whatever, all of which is just guesswork anyway.

Comment: There's `|>` in F# and `%>%` in R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do pipelining type parallelism quite easily in Erlang. Below is a shameless copy/paste from my blogpost of Jan 2008.

Also, [Glasgow Parallel Haskell](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~dsg/gph/) allows for parallel function composition, which amounts to the same thing, giving you implicit parallelisation.

> You already think in terms of
>   pipelines - how about "gzcat
>   foo.tar.gz | tar xf -"? You may not
>   have known it, but the shell is
>   running the unzip and untar in
>   parallel - the stdin read in tar just
>   blocks until data is sent to stdout by
>   gzcat.
>
> Well a lot of tasks can be expressed
>   in terms of pipelines, and if you can
>   do that then getting some level of
>   parallelisation is simple with David
>   King's helper code (even across erlang
>   nodes, ie. machines):
>
> ```
> pipeline:run([pipeline:generator(BigList),
>           {filter,fun some_filter/1},
>           {map,fun_some_map/1},
>           {generic,fun some_complex_function/2},
>           fun some_more_complicated_function/1,
>           fun pipeline:collect/1]).
> ```
>
> So basically what he's doing here is
>   making a list of the steps - each step
>   being implemented in a fun that
>   accepts as input whatever the previous
>   step outputs (the funs can even be
>   defined inline of course). Go check
>   out David's [blog entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20080516071309/http://www.ketralnis.com/roller/dking/entry/20080108) for the
>   code and more detailed explanation.

Comment: This is very much along the lines of what I am thinking about. I need to study it a bit more tomorrow after some coffee!

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it is the most elegant solution I saw and Mark pointed me to Hartmann pipelines in the above comment, which lead me to Flow-based programming.

Comment: Is map-reduce an example of a pipeline? I really like JavaScript's built-in functions fire that. But I too am  disappointed even golang has no special syntax like bash does

Answer (score 13):

Haha! Thanks to my Google-fu, I have found [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552260/rules-of-thumb-for-when-to-use-operator-overloading-in-python/1552292#1552292) that may interest you. Basically, the answer is going against the "don't overload operators unless you really have to" argument by overloading the bitwise-OR operator to provide shell-like piping, resulting in Python code like this:

```
for i in xrange(2,100) | sieve(2) | sieve(3) | sieve(5) | sieve(7):
    print i
```

What it does, conceptually, is pipe the list of numbers from 2 to 99 (`xrange(2, 100)`) through a sieve function that removes multiples of a given number (first 2, then 3, then 5, then 7). This is the start of a prime-number generator, though generating prime numbers this way is a rather bad idea. But we can do more:

```
for i in xrange(2,100) | strify() | startswith(5):
    print i
```

This generates the range, then converts all of them from numbers to strings, and then filters out anything that doesn't start with 5.

The post shows a basic parent class that allows you to overload two methods, `map` and `filter`, to describe the behavior of your pipe. So `strify()` uses the `map` method to convert everything to a string, while `sieve()` uses the `filter` method to weed out things that aren't multiples of the number.

It's quite clever, though perhaps that means it's not very Pythonic, but it demonstrates what you are after and a technique to get it that can probably be applied easily to other languages.

Comment: Not bad. I voted up of course, but my qualms are none of the functions are executed in parallel. What I really want is something more like the Erlang and Java answers.

Comment: @cdiggins - Your qualms are an implementation detail. This same functionality could have easily been implemented in C (or even assembly?) to take advantage of parallelism, and because all the brute work is done in the base class, derived classes written in pure Python would still get that power (the two methods that you have to overload - `map` and `filter` - only work on one element at a time). Of course, if we're willing to implement it, we could do the same for most regular functional constructs, with or without the Unix-pipe interface.

Comment: I'm actually not surprised that you can't use the pipe character itself, but I'm a little disappointed that there's no easy "concurrent data pipes" available in some way.
Something like
`concat_file(myfile) |> filter("mypattern") |> write_file(myoutfile)` (or something of the sorts) could work, right?

Basically it would create 3 threads and send data from one to the other in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

`magrittr` [package](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) provides something similar to F#'s pipe-forward operator in R:

```
rnorm(100) %>% abs %>% mean
```

Combined with `dplyr` package, it brings a neat data manipulation tool:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "virginica") %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  colMeans
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find something like pipes in C# and Java, for example, where you take a connection stream and put it inside the constructor of another connection stream.

So, you have in Java:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

You may want to look up chaining input streams or output streams.

Comment: I was thinking more about two separate processes running in parallel one spitting out data, and the other consuming data.

Comment: Then you just use a PipedInput (Output) Stream: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html, but this is not in parallel, but you can convert data as you go through the streams.

Comment: @James, the PipedInputStream and PipedOutStream is very close to what I am looking for. I was wondering about first class support for this thing (with automatic parallelism) in languages. Turns out that what I was looking for is called "flow programming". Thank you very much though for showing me some cool Java stuff.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to think "backwards": when reading the code, you first read the last function and end with the first applied function. I.e. the order is reversed as compared to shell's pipe, and to the order of operations. I would prefer something like `System.in | (new InputStreamReader) | (new BufferedReader)`

Comment: @jrouquie - In functional programming type languages this is now easier to do, using F# or Scala, for example, to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to all of the great answers and comments, here is a summary of what I learned:

It turns out that there is an entire paradigm related to what I am interested in called [Flow-based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming). A good example of a language designed specially for flow-based programming is [Hartmann pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartmann_pipelines). Hartamnn pipelines generalize the idea of streams and pipes used in Unix and other OS's, to allows for multiple input and output streams (rather than just a single input stream, and two output streams). [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) contains powerful abstractions that make it easy to express concurrent processes in a manner which resembles pipes. Java provides [PipedInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [PipedOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) which can be used with threads to achieve the same kind of abstractions in a more verbose manner.

Comment: And thank you for posting the question. Id been wondering for a while the same thing but was discouraged from asking due to the hostile environment stack overflow is

Answer (score 3):

I think the most fundamental reason is because C# and Java tend to be used to build more monolithic systems.  Culturally, it's just not common to even want to do pipe-like things -- you just make your application implement the necessary functionality.  The notion of building a multitude of simple tools and then gluing them together in arbitrary ways just isn't common in those contexts.

If you look at some of the scripting languages, like Python and Ruby, there are some pretty good tools for doing pipe-like things from within those scripts.  Check out the Python subprocess module, for example, which allows you to do things like:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('cat -',
                       shell=True,
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
print '\tpass through:', stdout_value
```

Comment: ISn't this just driving the Shell's pipe from Python? As I understand it, the OP's question is about having a pipe-like construct inside the language.

Comment: Interesting, I thought all pipes just wrapped the os pipes just like threads but now that you mention it I am wondering when are they and are they not their own implementation of the paradigm. Id like to think we shouldn't reinvent the wheel but this is hardcore stuff I may not have a deep awareness of. All I know is I like pipelines

Answer (score 3):

Usually you just don't need it and programs run faster without it.

Basically piping is consumer/producer pattern. And it's not that hard to write those consumers and producers because they don't share much data.

- Piping for Python : [pypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypes)
- Mozart-OZ can do pipes using ports and threads.

Comment: Pypes, is very awesome and much along the lines of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking at the F# |> operator? I think you actually want the >> operator.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C has the [NSPipe](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  I use it quite frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Since R added pipe operator today, it's worth to mention Julialang has pipe all a long:

```
help?> |>
search: |>

  |>(x, f)


  Applies a function to the preceding argument. This allows for easy function chaining.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> [1:5;] |> x->x.^2 |> sum |> inv
  0.01818181818181818
```

Comment: Wow, did R only recently introduce this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of fun building pipeline functions in Python.  I have a library I wrote, I put the contents and a sample run [here](http://pastebin.com/m211d3e91).  The best fit me for has been XML processing, described in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

You can do pipe like operations in Java by chaining/filtering/transforming iterators.
You can use Google's [Guava Iterators](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html).

I will say even with the very helpful guava library and static imports its still ends up being lots of Java code.

In Scala its quite easy to make your own pipe operator.

Comment: I'd been using those for years not realizing they were to aid concurrency!

Answer (score 1):

Streaming libraries based on coroutines have existed in Haskell for quite some time now. Two popular examples are [conduit](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview) and [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Both libraries are well-written and well-documented, and are relatively mature. The [Yesod](http://yesodweb.com/) web framework is based on conduit, and it's [pretty damn fast](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r5). Yesod is competitive with Node on performance, even beating it in a few places.

Interestingly, all of the these libraries are single-threaded by default. This is because the single motivating use case for pipelines is servers, which are I/O bound.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still interested in an answer...

you can look at factor, or the older joy and forth for the concatenative paradigm.
in arguments and out arguments are implicit, dumped to a stack. then the next word (function) takes that data and does something with it.

the syntax is postfix.

"123" print

where print takes one argument, whatever is in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library in python: [github.com/sspipe/sspipe](https://github.com/sspipe/sspipe)

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica, you can use `//`

for example

```
f[g[h[x,parm1],parm2]]
```

quite a mess.

could be written as

```
x // h[#, parm1]& // g[#, parm2]& // f
```

the # and & is lambda in Mathematica

---

In js, there seems to be pipe operator `|>` soon.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator