# Can custom formatting through the % operator be done in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is it possible to have a class be formatted in its own specific way with the `%` operator, in Python? I am interested in a case where the format string would be something like `%3z` (not simply `%s` or `%r`, which are handled by the `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods). Said differently: Python 2.6+ allows classes to define a `__format__()` method: is there an equivalent for the `%` operator?

I tried to define the `__rmod()__` method, hoping that `str.__mod__()` would return `NotImplemented` and that `__rmod()__` would be called, but `"%3z" % …` returns `ValueError: unsupported format character 'z'` instead…

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done.  Is there any reason why you're avoiding using format?

Comment: There is a reason: the formatting will be applied to the numbers with uncertainty of my uncertainties package, which works with all version of Python *starting with 2.3* (versions 2.3 to 2.5 only have `%` and not `format()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. This customizability is one of the major benefits of the `format` method over `%` formatting. If it wasn't novel, [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) wouldn't need to discuss this aspect of it in so much detail.

If you need to support older versions of Python than have new-style string formatting, the best you can do is to implement a custom conversion function on your class, and expect clients to call it like this:

```
'%4f %s' % (5, myobj.str('<'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You might find this helpful:
[operator overloading in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936135/operator-overloading-in-python)

__mod__ and __rmod__ are included here:
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Don't bother trying to reinvent Python's string formatting mini-language...use it to your advantage:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

EDIT: you probably got at least this far, but since we're here to code:

```
class moddableObject(object):
    def __mod__(self, arg)
        return 'got format arg: {}'.format(arg)

moddable = moddableObject()
print moddable % 'some string'
```

Comment: OP clearly already knows how operator overloading works - he has specifically tried implementing `moddableObject.__rmod__` to find that `'some string' % moddable` doesn't call it (since `str.__mod__` raises an exception rather than returning `NotImplemented`).

Comment: hence my comment, "you probably got at least this far, but since we're here to code"...I put it there so others could see a quick example (and so I could try it out myself).