# When to use x.__lshift__ and x.__pow__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently studying the methods for each built-in function, many apply to other functions. I came across 2 methods withing the `bool()` function: `x.__lshift__` and `x.__pow__`. Now, `x.__lshift__(y)` equates to `x<<y` while `x.__pow__(y[, z])` equates to `pow(x, y[, z])`.

**My Question:** These two methods appear to be almost the same ( I used them within the shell to check, if this question seems to be not thought out I probably used them incorrectly), **What is the difference, usage with `bool()`, between the two?**

Comment: They're different functions!

Comment: @Antimony .... difference in USAGE of the methods in the `bool()` function

Comment: Do you have a link to the source handy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you are allowed to overload operators by overriding some special member methods. You can change the behavior of << operator by overriding **lshift**. This is the same to other operators and their corresponding functions.

See this:[operator overloading in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936135/operator-overloading-in-python)