# Can I specify accessor methods for operations other than get and set?

Tags: python, getter-setter

I have a python class `A` with attribute `instance_b` as follows :

```
class A(object):

    instance_b = 0

    def getB(self):
        # Do something Fancy here
        return self.instance_b

    def setB(self, value):
        # Do something Fancy here
        self.instance_B = value

    b = property(getB, setB)
```

The `property()` function allows me to specify a getter and setter. But is there a way I can specify an incrementer and decrementer? Can I specify similar methods for other operations?

More importantly to me, what if `instance_b` is a list instead of an integer. Can I set methods that will substitute for ".insert()" and "+=" and "[-1]"?

Or are only getters and setters (and deletes) allowed to be specified..... And I have to use them to do what I need. So adding an element to the list `instance_b` would need to look something like this?

```
a = A()
a.b = a.b + ["my_item"]
```

Comment: Operator overloading is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936135/operator-overloading-in-python

Comment: Replace value with a subclass of list then it is easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

"if instance_b is a list instead of an integer" you could perfectly well call list methods on it after `getB` returns it.  If you need to intercept some list methods (or operators, &c), then you need to return the list wrapped into a class of your own that does the interception.

So the simple case might be...:

```
class A(object):

    instance_b = []

    def getB(self):
        # Do something Fancy here
        return self.instance_b

    def setB(self, value):
        # Do something Fancy here
        self.instance_B = value

    b = property(getB, setB)
```

Now for example:

```
a = A()
a.b.append(23)
print(a.b)
```

displays `[23]` as expected.

Now supposed that for devious reasons of your own you want `append` on `a.b` to act **twice** (while other list methods work normally, and you don't care about operators).  This requires a simple wrapper class:

```
class Double(object):
    def __init__(self, alist):
        self.alist = alist

    def append(self, v):
        self.alist.extend((v,v))

    def getattr(self, n):
        return getattr(self.alist, n)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.alist)
```

and changing your `getB` to `return Doubt(self.instance_B)`.  Now, the same code as before displays `[23, 23]` -- again as expected.

Intercepting operators is also quite possible, just a bit more laborious, and I'll leave that as an exercise to the interested reader:-).

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the bug in your code, then the `property` function with basic getter and setter methods like that will allow you to do everything you mentioned:

```
class A(object):

    instance_b = 0

    def getB(self):
        # Do something Fancy here
        return self.instance_b

    def setB(self, value):
        # Do something Fancy here
        self.instance_b = value  # <-- this line in your code was wrong

    b = property(getB, setB)

a = A()
print(a.b)               # --> 0
a.b += 42
print(a.b)               # --> 42
a.b = []                 # replace with an empty list
print(a.b)               # --> []
a.b = a.b + ["my_item"]
print(a.b)               # --> ['my_item']
a.b.insert(0, 23)
print(a.b)               # --> [23, 'my_item']
print(a.b[-1])           # --> my_item
```