# python function name limitations

Tags: python, function

I'm wondering if there is anyway around the typical limitations on python function names (alphanumerics etc).

Typical function application proceeds like this `myFunction(arg1,arg2)`. But we know there are exceptions, such as functions that use *infix* notation. As example, consider `3 + 5`. Here, the addition function uses infix notation, and also has a rather special name `+`.

My question is if there is any way (perhaps with aliases) to give a function a name that is a special character such as `+` or `~`. This possibility obviously exists in core python, but is there a way utilize this with defined functions? Thanks

Comment: `+` is syntax which maps to the [`object.__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method. You can't create new syntax, you can only create new objects.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can extend the parser if you really want, but it's unlikely to be worth the effort.

Comment: Just trying to understand the special case `+`  and wondering if I could utilize something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if there is any way (perhaps with aliases) to give a function a name that is a special character such as + or ~.

No. For a handful of cases you might be able to do something similar though:

Python doesn't have the concept of infix functions, like e.g. Haskell does.

The operators that it does have (`+`, `-`, `*`) are hardcoded in the sense that you can't add new ones, however, you can override what each of these operators do when applied to a particular type. This is called operator overloading and is described [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936135/operator-overloading-in-python).