# Writing a Python C type, and want to write a multiplication operator

Tags: python, cpython

I'm writing a special numerical type for Python in C as an extension, and I want to provide it with a specialized binary multiplication operator.

```
static PyMethodDef pyquat_Quat_methods[] = {
  {"__mul__", (PyCFunction)pyquat_Quat_mul, METH_O, "multiply unit quaternion by another using the Hamiltonian definition"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

If I then compile and load the library, I can successfully create instances of the object called x and y. I can even do

```
w = x.__mul__(y)
```

But if I try to do

```
w = x * y
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'pyquat.Quat' and 'pyquat.Quat'
```

Is there some way I need to tell Python to treat `__mul__` as the binary multiplication operator?

Comment: Overloading operators seems to be possible with classes, so e.g. *, + between two objects of the class can be defined using _ _mul_ _ and _ _add_ _ (had to add the space between the _ or the double _ gets consumed as bold formatting) method definitions in the class, see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python. BTW all I did was search for _python operator overload_ and this was the top answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936135/operator-overloading-in-python

Comment: @barny - re: formatting. Try adding backticks: `\`__mul__\``

Comment: doh knew that worked in answer, never tried it in comment. Thanks!

Comment: @barny: That's what the questioner already tried, and it didn't work, because the C API way of overloading operators is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a type written in C to support multiplication, you need to provide a [`tp_as_number` field](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_number) with an `nb_multiply` function for multiplication, and you need to *not* explicitly provide a `__mul__` method. `__mul__` will be handled for you. It may help to look at [how built-in types do it](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c).

Comment: So if 'mul will be handled for you' - I guess you mean you put a pointer to the multiply (and all the other operator functions) in the `PyNumberMethods` structure.

Comment: @barny: Provide a `tp_as_number` field with pointers to your multiplication and other methods, and Python will set `__mul__` for you.