# python operator overload and friends

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword

I wanted to know if anyone could give me an example of how to overload an operator within a class, in my case the + operator. Could I define a function (not a class method) that does it? I'm a newbie so I don't really know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Being a newbie doesn't really explain why you're not searching. No offense meant - it's generally in one's best interest to search before asking, as one usually gets more answers in less time.

Comment: Covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552260/rules-of-thumb-for-when-to-use-operator-overloading-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyNum(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super(MyNum,self).__init__()
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, num):
        return self.__class__.(self.val + num)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(' + str(self.val) + ')'

print(MyNum(3) + 2)   # -> MyNum(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Define its `__add__()` method.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt of the basics: manual.
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Just to point out, I have recently been searching about overloading, and it would never have occurred to me to use the phrase "datamodel".  I used "overloading" in the docs and got no relevant hits.

Comment: OK, I had a look, and the _only_ mention I could find of the "magic functions" was in the topic "3.3.8. Emulating numeric types".  Still didn't mention overloading though, still less show how it is done.  I feel compelled to downvote your answer, but I can't.