# Accessing Methods of a class using function parameter in python

Tags: python

I have a class like this in python:

```
class xyz:
    def abc():
          #Do Something
            def add(x,y):
                  #Add x and y
            def sub(x,y):
                  #Subtract y from x
            def mul(x,y):
                  #multiply x ynd y
```

Note: Here "add", "sub" and "mul" are nested methods.

1. Is it allowed to make a class like this?
2. If it is allowed, then i want to access the methods "add", "sub" and "mul" by function parameters. for e.g.:

   ```
   from xyz import xyz
   def jkl(input):
          abc.(input)  # By doing this it will raise syntax error. This is just for refernece.
   ```

so, when i call jkl(add(2,3)) it should add the numbers. Similarly when i call jkl(sub(4,3)) it should subtract the numbers.

Can it be done?

Comment: You can overload standard operators. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438574/python-operator-overload-and-friends

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but please use `#` instead of `//` for comments in Python. String literals are good too.

Comment: Just a thought: you could create a dictionary and assign functions to the dictionary values. So that way you can do jkl(key="add", args=(2,3)) which would then call abc[key](args). But there's probably a different approach to whatever it is you're really trying to do that would work better.

Comment: It might be just me, but I can't follow what you're trying to do. What is your `def abc:` block supposed to do? It just causes a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like OP is attempting to use a class as a module/package. This answer to this question will need to explain how module/package imports work. Either that, or staticmethod.

Comment: You aren't using the class `xyz` at all in the example of what you want to do. Please edit your question to show clearly what you want to do, with less abstract names if possible.

Comment: Also: as written, your code will raise a `SyntaxError`. You have to have parentheses after `def abc`, viz. `def abc():`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand exactly what your goal is here.

EDIT: I'll leave this answer here since it has received an upvote, but OP clarified that they're actually asking how to overload operators.

You can do this:

```
class abc():
      //Do Something
      @staticmethod
      def add(x,y):
              # Add x and y
      @staticmethod
      def sub(x,y):
              # Subtract y from x
      @staticmethod
      def mul(x,y):
              # multiply x ynd y

abc.add(1,1)
```

If you want to use your class in another module, you can put that class definition in file `xyz.py`, and then in another file (in the same directory):

```
from xyz import abc

abc.add(1,1)
```

However, this is a very odd thing to do in the Python world. I'd advise organizing things differently, unless you have a really good reason to do things this way. A better way would be to skip the class definition altogether, and do this in `abc.py`:

```
def add(x,y):
          # Add x and y
def sub(x,y):
          # Subtract y from x
def mul(x,y):
          # multiply x ynd y
```

Then import from that module:

```
import abc

abc.add(1,1)
etc...
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
from abc import add, sub, mul

add(1,1)
etc...
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just need to overload standard operators. Thnx.

Comment: @sats I'd suggest completely rewriting your question before it gets closed, then! Or just starting over.