# How and where to use Python's __and__, __or__, __invert__ magic methods properly

Tags: python, magic-methods

I was googling around to find any use cases or examples of these methods but could not find any detailed explanation, they are just listed along other similar methods. Actually, I was looking through some code on github and came across these methods but could not understand the usage. Can somebody please provide a detailed explanation of these methods. This is the link of github code where I came across them: https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/queries.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic methods `__and__`, `__or__` and `__invert__` are used to override the operators `a & b`, `a | b` and `~a` respectively. That is, if we have a class

```
class QueryImpl(object):
    def __and__(self, other):
        return ...
```

then

```
a = QueryImpl(...)
b = QueryImpl(...)
c = a & b
```

is equivalent to

```
a = QueryImpl(...)
b = QueryImpl(...)
c = a.__and__(b)
```

These methods are overridden in `tinydb` to support this syntax:

```
>>> db.find(where('field1').exists() & where('field2') == 5)
>>> db.find(where('field1').exists() | where('field2') == 5)
#                                    ^
```

See also:

- [Python's reference on `__and__`, `__or__` and friends](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)
- [Rules of thumb for when to use operator overloading in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552260/rules-of-thumb-for-when-to-use-operator-overloading-in-python)