# Overload the necessary operator(s) so that instead of having to write

Tags: python-3.x

Doing some exercises from Think like a CS with Python 3:
Have a task:
Overload the necessary operator(s) that instead of having to write

```
if t1.after(t2):...
```

we can use the more convenient

```
if t1 > t2: ...
```

How I can do it? Have no ideas.

Comment: Look at [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/), and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__gt__#object.__gt__).

Comment: What have you tried so far, where exactly do you struggle with this task?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. You can use the `__gt__` operator.

Comment: @rassar thx got it)

Comment: You should really search stack overflow for your question before you post it. There are many answers about operator overloading already. Here's one questions with several: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552260/rules-of-thumb-for-when-to-use-operator-overloading-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `t1.__gt__(t2)` method of your class. I would suggest overriding all of the following `__gt__` `__lt__` `__le__` `__ge__` special functions.

For example

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def __lt__(self,other):
        self_mag = (self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)
        other_mag = (other.x ** 2) + (other.y ** 2)
        return self_mag < other_mag
```

will allow you to write expressions like `p1 < p2` but not `p1 > p2`. But it can be done trivially.

edit: turns out that simply overriding the `__eq__` and `__lt__` on top of using `functools.@total_ordering` gives the desired result.