# += operator in python for __setitem__ (addition in place for square brackets)

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-overloading

To define a class behaviour in the following statement:

```
my_object[item] = ...
```

I know I need to define the `__setitem__` method.

What method do I need to define for the following statement:

```
my_object[item] += ...
```

Comment: You are looking for `__iadd__` I believe.

Comment: The question was answered [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047021/overriding-in-python-iadd-method)

Comment: There is no such thing as `__isetitem__`.  For `my_object[...]`, you can define `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, but to make `my_object[item] += ...` different from `my_object[item] = my_object[item] + ...`, you would need to modify the class that `my_object[item]` is an instance of.

Comment: @Hang: no, that answer does not address this question. The accepted answer is correct. The point is that __iadd__ is not what is needed for this situation, but a correct implementation of __getitem__ besides __setitem__ is. That is not obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my_object` needs `__getitem__` to retrieve the initial value of `my_object[item]` and `__setitem__` to set the new value.

Additionally, Python needs a way to perform the addition. Either `my_object[item]` needs to implement the addition with `__add__` or `__iadd__`, or the object on the right side of the `+=` needs to implement `__radd__`.

Answer (score 1):

`__setitem__` will cover you with regard to your container class; it's called when you do any augmented assignment just as with regular assignment. As far as your class can tell, there's no difference between `x[i] += 1` and `x[i] = x[i] + 1`.

If you need to treat `+=` differently from `=` or from `-=`, that's handled by the special methods of the *item's* class.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, it always helps to use `dis.dis` to see the bytecode of corresponding code. E.g.:

```py
import dis

def f(x):
    x[2] += 3

print(dis.dis(f))
```

You get:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 DUP_TOP_TWO
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 INPLACE_ADD
             12 ROT_THREE
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR) or [here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/dis.html) on what those ops do exactly. E.g. `BINARY_SUBSCR` implements:

```py
key = STACK.pop()
container = STACK.pop()
STACK.append(container[key])
```

So, it means, this Python code is basically doing this:

```
# DUP_TOP_TWO will store the container and key on the hash,
# so that it is reused for both BINARY_SUBSCR
# and the later STORE_SUBSCR.
key = 2
value = 3
item_value = x[key]  # BINARY_SUBSCR
item_value += value  # INPLACE_ADD
x[key] = item_value  # STORE_SUBSCR
```