# How come self.__add__(a) and self + a doesn't return the same values in dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm taking a Python course and the exercise is to create a class in which you can append a dictionnary to another by typing : `dict1 = dict1 + dict2`

So this is done by creating an `__add__` method in the class, because `dict1 + dict2` is the same as typing `dict1.__add__(dict2)` , right ? Except that if I type those 2 commands they don't return the same value. This is an extract of my code :

```
class zDict(dict):
...
     def __add__(self, otherDict):
         otherDict = [(k,v) for k,v in otherDict.items()]
         print("passed through zDict.__add__") #just to make sure           
         for key, value in otherDict:
             self[key]=value
...
```

So now if we run this with 2 zDict objects, `dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}` and `dict2 = {'d':4,'e':5}` for examples,  here are the results (Python 3.6.6) :

```
>>> dict1.__add__(dict2)
passed through zDict.__add__
>>> dict1
>>> {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}
>>> type(dict1)
>>> <class '__main__.zDict'>

RESTART

>>> dict1 += dict2
passed through zDict.__add__
>>> dict1

>>> type(dict1)
>>> <class 'NoneType'>
```

So I don't understand there. I typed the same thing but got different results. `dict1 = dict1 + dict2` is the same as typing `dict1 += dict2`, which is the same as typing `dict1 = dict1.__add__(dict2)`, right ? And I made sure they pass through the same method with print. It can't come from the `dict class`, because it doesn't have any `__add__` method. Maybe it passes through a method from a parent class like object, who changes the type to `NoneType` ? How can I check that, and prevent it ?

Comment: This is because you are not returning anything from `__add__`

Answer (score 1):

`zDict.__add__()` will return `None` (i.e. you change self in place)
`dict1 += dict2` is same as `dict1 = dict1.__add__(dict2)`

also why not use `dict.update()`?

Comment: For some reason dict.update() returns noneType as well

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is implemented using the `__iadd__` method, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047021/overriding-in-python-iadd-method)