# Override __isub__ operator over specific attribute

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Resources:
    """
    Resources class.
    """

    def __init__(self, food: int, gold: int):
        self.F = food
        self.G = gold

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Resources(self.F - other.F, self.G - other.G)

    def __getitem__(self, attr):
        return self.__getattribute__(attr)
```

I am coding another class for buying / selling specific resources. The part Im struggling with is this:

```
a = Resources(100, 200)
a['F'] -= 50
```

When executed, TypeError: 'Resources' object does not support item assignment

I can get any attribute once I know its name, but I don't know how to change its value through the -= operator.

So, to clarify, the question is: How to substract a float value to a given attribute selected by using a string, and store the result in the same attribute?

Comment: You need to implement `__setitem__`

Comment: I tried, by ```__setitem__``` requires the value to set as a parameter. How to pass to ```__setitem__```  the current value of the attribute minus the value to substract?

Comment: Are you trying to subtract 50 from object `a`'s `F` attribute? You can't access attributes via indexing, you have to use `a.F` (or `getattr(a, "F")`).

Comment: @AdamKern, I am doing that because I want to select the attribute to modify as a string parameter in a function.

Comment: @AlanWik ah I'm sorry I didn't see the `__getitem__` override, although generally speaking I'm not sure that overriding `__getitem__` to perform dynamic attribute access is best practices, since that functionality is built in to Python via the `getattr` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to the post-edit question:

```
def reduce_resource(self, resource_name, value):
    setattr(self, resource_name, getattr(resource_name) - value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do

```
self.resources[what] = self.resources[what] - amount
```

or implement the `__isub__()` method in your `Resources` class, which is called when the `-=` operator is used (just like the `-` operator calls the `__sub__()` method).

```
# mutating this object
def __isub__(self, other):
    self.F -= other.F
    self.G -= other.G
    return self

# not mutating this object, returning a copy that will be assigned over the original
def __isub__(self, other):
    return self - other  # delegate to __sub__()
```

(a similar method, `__rsub__()`, exists for if your object is used on the *right* side of a `-` sign instead of the left side. Note that this trio of methods exists for most operators).

---

Be careful to check whether your `Resources` objects should be mutable or immutable. The procedure for `x -= y` unrolls to `x = x.__isub__(y)`, so the method *can* be built without mutating the original `x`, as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546707/2648811).

Comment: [this answer addresses the title of the question and its pre-edit contents. The post-edit contents have a different error]

Comment: But that forces me to create another Resources instance only to store the value I want to sell, which is not a bad idea after all. But, what I would like to achieve is to substract a float value to a given attribute of an object selected with a string.

Comment: @AlanWik if that's the case, I think the easiest way to do it would be (given the attribute name `attr_name`) to just say `setattr(a, attr_name, getattr(a, attr_name) - 50)`. There's no need to override `__sub__`, since that seems to imply that you're subtracting from *the entire object*, not just a single attribute

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research I found this solution:

```
name = 'G'
amount = 50

a = Resources(100, 200)
vars(self.resources)[name] -= amount
```