# python3.x scope in finally

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Python==3.6.9*

```
def test():
    a = 2
    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as exc:
        return a
    finally:
        a += 1
        print(a)

print(test())
```

output is:

```
3
2
```

It's obvious that finally executes before return,  if `a` is a immutable type, `id(a)` is different between `finally scope` and `try\except scope`;

I want to know how did this happen? Thanks

Comment: `try` block has no scope in python. For the new `id(a)` explanation look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047021/overriding-in-python-iadd-method.

Comment: The mechanism behind the try statement has to ensure the finally block runs, so if you return from the try or catch blocks the value to return (in this case `2`, as that's what `a` is when the return statement is reached) is stored to be returned once the finally block has run (unless you return from the finally block, in which case that stored value is discarded).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, your answer is very useful, can i understand that finally stores information like a function, but does not use it if return before?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `try` statement does not create its own scope. Modules, classes, and functions create scope.

A complete description of [Python scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) in the docs.

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically.
> At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes
> whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names

Comment: Seems like this answer does not address the elements of the question directly. There isn't any variable called `b`. There is no `add` function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about the `finally` block is that it guarantees an operation is executed when we exit the scope of the `try-catch` block. We are *forced* to exit the scope when we `return` from the function. So, before we `return` we do the guaranteed task in the `finally` block first. If we didn't do this task, there can be bad consequences. For Eg :

Assume I create a connection in `try` block and I close it in `finally` block. If I return the connection in the `catch` block without closing it in the `finally` block, the function caller can start operating on a supposedly dead connection.

Hence, as you already know, if we didn't have `return` :

```
def test():
    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as exc:
        print("hi")
    finally:
        print("bye)

print(test())
```

The output will be

```
hi
bye
```