# I need a Python class that keep tracks of how many times it is instantiated

Tags: python, class, instances

I need a class that works like this:

```
>>> a=Foo()
>>> b=Foo()
>>> c=Foo()
>>> c.i
3
```

Here is my try:

```
class Foo(object):
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.i += 1
```

It works as required, but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Comment: what is with the word pythonic? if it works in python... isn't that python**ic**?

Comment: No need to waste time implementing any other way

Comment: I take "pythonic" to mean "in the python idiom".  It's possible to write Python like a Java programmer, which doesn't necessarily show off its best qualities or style.

Comment: Pythonic is taken to mean "idiomatic python" or code that follows general Python conventions and guidelines.  As opposed to Python code that was clearly written by a Java developer, for example.  The difference becomes obvious.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe we basically wrote the same response...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045344/how-do-you-create-an-incremental-id-in-a-python-class

Comment: Works in Python is not always Pythonic.  Look at some of the SO questions from Python beginners -- sometimes the post remarkably un-pythonic code.  Hard to read, bad use of language, libraries and idiom.

Comment: It took me some time to understand what pythonic is, and certainly is not easy to gasp it if you are not a Python programmer. Not all my code is Pythonic but at least most of the time I recognize pythonic code when I see it.

Comment: Nitpick: "instantiated"

It wouldn't matter except that it will make it easier to search for this question.

Comment: I shouldn't have posted so quickly. According to Wiktionary, both spellings are acceptable. Nevermind.

Comment: Please see my answer if you want to take a threadsafe approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope. That's pretty good.

From The Zen of Python: "Simple is better than complex."

That works fine and is clear on what you're doing, don't complicate it. Maybe name it `counter` or something, but other than that you're good to go as far as pythonic goes.

Comment: Maybe I should post my comment here, instead of on the question: I'm just curious, is something like this threadsafe? Would you be able to instantiate Foo from multiple threads and have a proper count?

Comment: @Tom: Good question. I honestly am not sure, but I would think that it does.

Comment: I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072821/is-modifying-a-class-variable-in-python-threadsafe.

Answer (score 5):

Abuse of decorators and metaclasses.

```
def counting(cls):
    class MetaClass(getattr(cls, '__class__', type)):
        __counter = 0
        def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
            old_init = attrs.get('__init__')
            def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
                MetaClass.__counter += 1
                if old_init: return old_init(*args, **kwargs)
            @classmethod
            def get_counter(cls):
                return MetaClass.__counter
            new_attrs = dict(attrs)
            new_attrs.update({'__init__': __init__, 'get_counter': get_counter})
            return super(MetaClass, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, new_attrs)
    return MetaClass(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls.__dict__)

@counting
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

print Foo.get_counter()    # ==> 0
print Foo().get_counter()  # ==> 1
print Bar.get_counter()    # ==> 1
print Bar().get_counter()  # ==> 2
print Foo.get_counter()    # ==> 2
print Foo().get_counter()  # ==> 3
```

You can tell it's Pythonic by the frequent use of double underscored names.  (Kidding, kidding...)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to worry about thread safety (so that the class variable can be modified from multiple threads that are instantiating `Foo`s), the above answer is in correct. I asked this question about thread safety [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072821/is-modifying-a-class-variable-in-python-threadsafe). In summary, you would have to do something like this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement # for python 2.5

import threading

class Foo(object):
  lock = threading.Lock()
  instance_count = 0

  def __init__(self):
    with Foo.lock:
      Foo.instance_count += 1
```

Now `Foo` may be instantiated from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

> **Could we use decorators ?  So for example ..**

```
class ClassCallCount:
    def __init__(self,dec_f):
        self._dec_f = dec_f
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._count +=1
        return self._dec_f(*args, **kwargs)

    def PrintCalled(self):
        return (self._count)


@ClassCallCount
def somefunc(someval):
    print ('Value : {0}'.format(someval))



    somefunc('val.1')
    somefunc('val.2')
    somefunc('val.3')
    somefunc('val.4')
    ## Get the # of times the class was called
    print ('of times class was called : {0}'.format(somefunc._count))
```

Comment: Is this a new Question or an Answer?