# Is modifying a class variable in python threadsafe?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071935/i-need-a-python-class-that-keep-tracks-of-how-many-times-it-is-instanciated) (which you do not have to read because I will copy what is there... I just wanted to give show you my inspiration)...

So, if I have a class that counts how many instances were created:

```
class Foo(object):
  instance_count = 0
  def __init__(self):
    Foo.instance_count += 1
```

My question is, if I create Foo objects in multiple threads, is instance_count going to be correct? Are class variables safe to modify from multiple threads?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not threadsafe even on CPython. Try this to see for yourself:

```
import threading

class Foo(object):
    instance_count = 0

def inc_by(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        Foo.instance_count += 1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=inc_by, args=(100000,)) for thread_nr in xrange(100)]
for thread in threads: thread.start()
for thread in threads: thread.join()

print(Foo.instance_count) # Expected 10M for threadsafe ops, I get around 5M
```

The reason is that while INPLACE_ADD is atomic under GIL, the attribute is still loaded and store (see *dis.dis(Foo.__init__)*). Use a lock to serialize the access to the class variable:

```
Foo.lock = threading.Lock()

def interlocked_inc(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        with Foo.lock:
            Foo.instance_count += 1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=interlocked_inc, args=(100000,)) for thread_nr in xrange(100)]
for thread in threads: thread.start()
for thread in threads: thread.join()

print(Foo.instance_count)
```

Comment: I believe in your second example you want the Thread target to be interlocked_inc instead of inc_by.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Too liberal copy&paste programming catches up with me sometimes.

Comment: Thank you Ants Aasma :-). This is as I suspected. Thank you for proving it to me. As tgray points out, your second target should be interlocked_inc. But once you change that... looks flawless.

Comment: Did modern Python3 (I am testing on Python3.10.4) release some fixes? As I tested the first part of the code multiple times and got an expected result of 10M directly, without any sync methods.

Answer (score 14):

No it is not thread safe. I've faced a similar problem a few days ago, and I chose to implement the lock thanks to a decorator. The benefit is that it makes the code readable:

```
def threadsafe_function(fn):
    """decorator making sure that the decorated function is thread safe"""
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def new(*args, **kwargs):
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            r = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            lock.release()
        return r
    return new

class X:
    var = 0

    @threadsafe_function     
    def inc_var(self):
        X.var += 1    
        return X.var
```

Comment: off-topic, but can you remove the two lock.release() calls to a "else:" section after the exception handler?

Comment: Do you mean in a finally section? Doing that in an else would not release when an exception is raised

Comment: Use "with" for locking this way.  It cleans up the above greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from luc's answer, here's a simplified decorator using `with` context manager and a little `__main__` code to spin up the test. Try it with and without the @synchronized decorator to see the difference.

```
import concurrent.futures
import functools
import logging
import threading


def synchronized(function):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Foo:
    counter = 0

    @synchronized
    def increase(self):
        Foo.counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    print(f"Start value is {foo.counter}")
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for index in range(200000):
            executor.submit(foo.increase)
    print(f"End value is {foo.counter}")
```

```
Without @synchronized
End value is 198124
End value is 196827
End value is 197968

With @synchronized
End value is 200000
End value is 200000
End value is 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is modifying a class variable in python threadsafe?

## It depends on the operation.

While the Python GIL ([Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)) only allows access to one thread at a time, per atomic operation, some operations are not atomic, that is, they are implemented with more than one operation, such as, given (L, L1, L2 are lists, D, D1, D2 are dicts, x, y are objects, i, j are ints)

```
i = i+1
L.append(L[-1])
L[i] = L[j]
D[x] = D[x] + 1
```

See [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)

You're example is included in the *non-safe* operations, as `+=` is short hand for `i = i + 1`.

Other posters have shown how to make the operation thread-safe. An alternative thread-safe way to implement your operation, without using a thread locking mechanism would be to reference a different variable, only set via an atomic operation. For example

```py
max_reached = False

# in one thread
count = 0
maximum = 100

count += 1
if count >= maximum:
    max_reached = True
    
# in another thread
while not max_reached:
    time.sleep(1)

# do something
```

This would be thread safe, as long as only one thread increments the count.

Answer (score -5):

I would say it is thread-safe, at least on CPython implementation. The GIL will make all your "threads" to run sequentially so they will not be able to mess with your reference count.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how the GIL works... but I still don't see it. Can't Thread1 read instance_count. Then thread1 stops. Thread2 reads instance_count, then stops. Thread1 modifies and writes. Thread2 writes. So you lose an increment? How does the GIL ensure the thread runs through the entire += operation?

Comment: Ha, I basically was asking what Sam Saffron asked just before me.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: I don't get the "atomic unit of work", it's a function call to __iadd__ method, so if you didn't overwrite it yes it is.
@Tom: It depends if instance_count is immutable or not. If it is immutable, you will lose the increment, else not (float and integers are immutable).

Comment: woops, looks I still need to learn :) Ants Aasma is damn right:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072821/is-modifying-a-class-variable-in-python-threadsafe/1073230#1073230