# Python2.7: How i can make countable ID's for each class object

Tags: python-2.7, oop

I want to give each employee I create in the Employee class an ID ***but automatically***

Here is the code:

```
class employees :
    def  __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'
        self.full_name = first + ' '+last
        self.facebook_link = 'FB.com/'+ self.full_name
```

Comment: For future reference, snippets only work for HTML, CSS, or javascript

Comment: By "countable" what do you mean? The easiest way to do this would be to create a uuid for each

Comment: example :
emp_1 have id 1
emp_2 have id 2
emp_33 have id 33 
and so on

Comment: across different runs of the app on different servers?

Comment: @MatthewStory i want to give an ID for each employee
like in  SQL is identity .

Comment: class employees :

    counter = 0

    def  __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'
        self.full_name = first + ' '+last
        self.facebook_link = 'FB.com/'+ self.full_name
        self.employee_id = employees.counter + 1
        employees.counter += 1

Comment: Wow, that was ugly - Just place a static counter variable in the class, assign it as the ID, and increment it immediately after assigning the ID within the __init__() function.

Comment: SLOVED 
THANKS ALOT 
i find it in :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045344/how-do-you-create-an-incremental-id-in-a-python-class?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class employees:
    uid = 0
    def  __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'
        self.full_name = first + ' '+last
        self.facebook_link = 'FB.com/'+ self.full_name

        employees.uid += 1
        self.uid = employees.uid
```

Now when I created by instances and print their `uid`

```
emp1 = employees('Abhishek', 'Babuji', 1000)
print(emp1.uid)
```

Output: 1

```
emp2 = employees('Abhishek1', 'Babuji1', 10001)
print(emp2.uid)
```

Output: 2

Every time you go inside `__init__` `employees.uid` gets incremented by 1 and then it is assigned to the instance using`self.uid`

Comment: How were you able to answer a closed question?

Comment: I already wrote out my answer before it became closed I think.

Comment: I wrote out this same answer almost immediately, and the submit button was gray. Weird, your answer came minutes after mine. Well - thumbs up!

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting You upvoted? Thanks for that! I'll see if I can return it.